# Pnpjs, How to surpress "Object is possibly 'undefined'" ts error on SharePoint context functions

Tags: typescript, pnpjs

For example I SP function, for example to format a date:

```
const friendlyDate = new Date().format("dd.MM.yyyy");
console.log(friendlyDate);
```

You can run in in Dev Tools on SharePoint page:

[image]

But if I use this code in ts project I get "Object is possibly 'undefined'" error ("Property 'format' does not exist on type 'Date'").

[image]

How to let my project know about functions that already exist in SharePoint context?..

Packages that I use in project:

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";

import { loadContext } from "@utils/env";
import { logger } from "@utils/logger";
import { setupPnp } from "@utils/odata";
```

Comment: Check this: https://marketsplash.com/tutorials/typescript/how-to-fix-object-is-possibly-undefined-typescript/

Comment: Thank You Ganesh, I've googled this article. In my case missing object is a sharepoint function; and I'm searching how to include it inside the project

Comment: `new Date()` is the JavaScript function which will work on any browser tab, not particular to SharePoint: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

Answer (score 0):

Well this 'format' method is from ASP.NET [MicrosoftAjax.js](https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5.2/1/MicrosoftAjax.js) old library

Tried to install it using

```
npm install @types/microsoft-ajax
```

and include types as

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "types": [
      "es6-promise",
      "es6-collections",
      "webpack-env",
      **"microsoft-ajax"**
    ]
  }
}
```

but with no success. Looks that I need to [link this js file as external library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-sharepoint-using-jsom); don't want to do it so finally ended up with:

```
let friendlyDate = new Date(itemData.Created).toLocaleString("en-us", { year: "numeric", month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit" }).replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/, "$2.$1.$3");
```

from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066586/get-string-in-yyyymmdd-format-from-js-date-object